# I am adding a tab layout with viewPager using fragments. The tab is dynamic on 0 tab is disabled and on 1 tab is enabled

Tags: java, android

I am adding a tab layout with viewPager using fragments. The tab is dynamic on 0 tab is disabled and on 1 tab is enabled.On disable the tab the tab position is gone but on swipe the next tab layout the content of fragment is repeating twice. How to solve it please help.

```
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkpurple));


        if (updateValue == true) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        } else if (updateNotice == true) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        } else if (updateGallery == true) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        } else if (updateClswork == true) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(3);
        } else if (updateEnquiry == true) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(4);
        } else if (updateCalender == true) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(5);
        }


        if (diary_view == 0) {

            tabPos = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
            tabLayout.removeTab(tabPos);

        } else if (notice_view == 0) {
            tabPos = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
            tabLayout.removeTab(tabPos);
        } else if (magical_moments_view == 0) {
            tabPos = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
            tabLayout.removeTab(tabPos);
        } else if (access_all_daily_class_work_view_listing == 0) {
            tabPos = tabLayout.getTabAt(3);
            tabLayout.removeTab(tabPos);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new ClassworkFrag()).commit();
        } else if (access_frontdesk_prospects_view == 0) {
            tabPos = tabLayout.getTabAt(4);
            tabLayout.removeTab(tabPos);
        } else if (institute_event_view == 0) {
            tabPos = tabLayout.getTabAt(5);
            tabLayout.removeTab(tabPos);
        }



        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        headerLayout = (RelativeLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);
        TextView nameTv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView enailidTv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        ImageView logoIv = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.logo);

        headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        nameTv.setText(usernameStr);
        enailidTv.setText(emailStr);

        logoIv.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        /*if (photoStr.isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .resize(50, 50)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(logoIv);
        }
        else {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(photoStr)
                    .resize(50, 50)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(logoIv);
        }*/

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPrefs.getString("listparent", null);
        Type type = (Type) new TypeToken<ArrayList<Parent>>() {
        }.getType();
        parentList = gson.fromJson(json, (Type) type);

        headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkpurple));
        toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));


        //Picasso.get().load(schoolBanner).into(bannerIv);

        /*Glide.with(this)
                .load(schoolBanner)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.coolgbnr)
                .into(bannerIv);*/
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load(schoolBanner)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.coolgbnr).error(R.drawable.coolgbnr))
                .into(bannerIv);


        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            int colorDiary = getResources().getColor(R.color.purple);
            int colorNotice = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            int colorCal = getResources().getColor(R.color.orange);
            int colorMm = getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal);
            int colorClswrk = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen);
            int colorEnquiry = getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold);

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
                if (tab != null) {
                    tab.select();
                }
                if (position == 0) {
                    headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkpurple));
                    toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
                    studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
                    fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
                    colorTitleBar(colorDiary);


                    if (create_diary == 1) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (create_diary == 0) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkcoloraccent));
                    toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    colorTitleBar(colorNotice);
                    if (create_notice == 1) {
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (create_notice == 0) {
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkpurpal));
                    toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal));
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal));
                    studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal));
                    fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purpal));
                    colorTitleBar(colorMm);

                    if (create_magical_moments == 1) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (create_magical_moments == 0) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected));
                    toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen));
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen));
                    studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen));
                    fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGoogleGreen));
                    colorTitleBar(colorClswrk);

                    if (create_class_work == 1) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (create_class_work == 0) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgold));
                    toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold));
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold));
                    studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold));
                    fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegold));
                    colorTitleBar(colorEnquiry);

                    if (create_institute_event == 1) {
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (create_institute_event == 0) {
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }


                } else if (position == 5) {
                    headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkorange));
                    toolbarCollapse.setContentScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    studetailLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    fabMenu.setMenuButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    colorTitleBar(colorCal);

                    if (create_institute_event == 1) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (create_institute_event == 0) {
                        //fabpostBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                fragPos = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        int position = 0;
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                Intent iArt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(iArt);
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_item_3:
                if (student_attendance == 1 || staff_attendance == 0) {
                    Intent iPro = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DialogActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iPro);
                } else if (student_attendance == 0 || staff_attendance == 1) {
                    Intent iPro = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DialogActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iPro);
                } else if (student_attendance == 0 || staff_attendance == 0) {
                    Intent iPro = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DialogActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iPro);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_item_4:
                Intent iScn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TeacherProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(iScn);
                break;

            case R.id.studentdetail:
                Intent iStudtl = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(iStudtl);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_item_5:
                sessionManage.logoutUser();
                break;

            case R.id.student:
                Intent report = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RootDialogActivity.class);
                startActivity(report);
                break;

            case R.id.attendance:
                if (view_attendance == 1) {
                    Intent report1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AttendanceReportActivity.class);
                    startActivity(report1);
                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Not Access",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.fee:
                if (fee_details == 1) {
                    Intent report2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FeeReportActivity.class);
                    startActivity(report2);
                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Not Access",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.payment:
                if (daily_report == 1) {
                    Intent report3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentReportActivity.class);
                    startActivity(report3);
                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Not Access",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

        }

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        CharSequence mTabname[] = new CharSequence[]{"Diary", "Notice", "Gallery", "Class\nWork", "Enquiry", "Calendar"};
        private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 6;
        Context context;
        int baseId =0;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.i("itemCount", "items = " + NUM_ITEMS);
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    if (diary_view==0){
                       new DiaryFrag().onDestroy();


                    }else {
                        DiaryFrag diaryFrag = new DiaryFrag();
                        return diaryFrag;
                    }


                case 1:
                    if (notice_view==0){
                        new NoticeFrag().onDestroy();


                    }else {


                        NoticeFrag noticeFrag = new NoticeFrag();
                        return noticeFrag;
                    }

                case 2:
                    if (magical_moments_view==0){
                        new GalleryFrag().onDestroy();

                    }else {
                        GalleryFrag galleryFrag = new GalleryFrag();
                        return galleryFrag;
                    }

                case 3:
                    if (access_all_daily_class_work_view_listing==0){

                    }else {
                        ClassworkFrag classworkFrag = new ClassworkFrag();
                        return classworkFrag;
                    }


                case 4:
                    if ((access_frontdesk_prospects_view == 0)) {

                    } else {
                        return new EnquiryFrag();
                    }


                case 5:
                    if (institute_event_view==0){

                    }else {
                        CalendarFrag calendarFrag = new CalendarFrag();
                        return calendarFrag;
                    }

            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mTabname[position];
        }
    }


    public void colorTitleBar(int color) {
       /* Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(color);*/
        //Log.d("colorcodee",""+color);

        try {
            Window window = getWindow();
            mainColor = color;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
                tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
                tintManager.setTintColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, mainColor));
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
               /* window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
                window.setStatusBarColor(mainColor);*/
                //Window window = getWindow();
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(color);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            //drawer is open
            drawer.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            MainActivity.this.finishAffinity();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method clearData() in adapter as:

```
private void clearData(){ 
    //clear your Array/List/ArrayList 
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

In your main activity, when you inflate the data in adapter, before setting data in it, clear the data using clearData().